# Calling angularjs scope function from href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, href, nvd3.js

I am using a library which appends a href element onto an  tag.  On this link I need to make a call to an angularjs function that is within scope.  Something like...

```
<a href="{{someFunction()}}"></a>
```

Note: I am attaching this href via javascript from another library (nvd3.js) not actually writing this in because if I was I could easily use ng-click or ng-href.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's a bit convoluted.

**CAVEAT**: This is very, very hacky and just absolutely exactly what you're **NOT** supposed to do in angular, but I guess you know that and the library is making your life hard...

First, unlike `onclick`, an `href` won't interpret a string as javascript. Instead, you'd have to use

```
<a href="javascript:someFunction()"></a>
```

But this alone won't make it work, because `someFunction()` is not a method on the `document`, but on the controller, so we need to get the controller first:

```
<a href="javascript:angular.element(
         document.getElementById('myController')).scope().someFunction();"></a>
```

Where `myController` refers to the DOM element that is decorated with `ng-controller`, e.g.

```
<div data-ng-controller="SomeController" id="myController"> ... </div>
```

If `someFunction` modifies the state of the view, you'll also need to use `$scope.apply`, i.e.

```
<a href="javascript:angular.element(document.getElementById('myController')).
           scope().$apply(someFunction)"></a>
```

Note that you don't need the `{{ }}` syntax, because you're calling javascript directly, you're not asking angular to modify your markup.

Comment: The most beautiful hack I have seen.  Works like a charm!

Comment: I thought it was working but jumped the gun: This is definitely the right track. Here is what I tried:angular.element('directive-name').scope().loadUsers(1); And the error said angular.element(...).scope(...).loadUsers is not a function.  When I type angular.element('directive-name') it returns the proper object with the scope() function on it.

Comment: Ok figured out I have to be on the $$childHead object first like so... angular.element("directive-name").scope().$$childHead and it works!

Answer (score 19):

So I was not pleased with the answer to this as it doesn't really utilize an elegant angular solution.

Here's my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jjosef/XwZ93

HTML:

```
<body class="wrapper" ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <a my-href="buildUrl('one', aVariable, 'three')">This is my a tag with a function that builds the url</a>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('ExampleApp', []);
angular.module('ExampleApp').run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.buildUrl = function() {
    var link = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      link.push(arguments[i].toLowerCase());
    }
    return '/#!/' + link.join('/');
  };

  $rootScope.aVariable = 'two';
});

angular.module('ExampleApp').directive('myHref', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var url = $parse(attrs.myHref)(scope);
      element.attr('href', url);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: this should be the top answer :/

Comment: You could you also use `scope.$eval` instead of `$parse` to avoid the need for dependency injection. See [modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gphjrc9/).

Comment: this code will not work if minified. see [modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XwZ93/46/) which will work with minification.

Answer (score 9):

You should probably use ng-click here.

Comment: The problem with `ng-click` is it would only detect clicks and not when the user navigates to the element with the Tab key and then press Space. In other words, the `click` event is not _semantic_.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is

```html
<a href="" ng-click="someFunction(x,y,z)">Go</a>
```

href="" is important, otherwise hover cursor style does not change to a pointer

Comment: See my comment above, `ng-click` handles the `click` DOM event, which is not semantic: it detects clicks but it doesn't detect when the user navigates to the element with the Tab key and then presses Space.

Answer (score 1):

I mixed some things here and I have it working.

I have a menu with some options, each one calls a different method on the controller.

```
<span ng-show="hoverOptions" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()" class="qk-select ui-select-container qk-select--div">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="option in menuOptions"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="callFunction(option.action)">{{option.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

The callFunction method in the controller is defined like that:

```
$scope.callFunction = function (name){
      if(angular.isFunction($scope[name]))
                $scope[name]();
}
```

And the menu options are defined also in the controller in that way:

```
$scope.menuOptions = [{action: "uploadPhoto" , name:"Cargar foto"}, {action: "logout", name:"Cerrar sesión"}, {action: "createUser", name:"Nuevo usuario"}];
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use $parse() to process the tag when using {{someFn}}.

Answer (score 0):

solution: https://embed.plnkr.co/bhMcEO/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>$window or $location to Redirect URL in AngularJS</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
      <script>
        var app = angular.module('RedirectURLApp', []);
        app.controller('RedirectURLCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
          $scope.name = 'Anil';
          $scope.RedirectToURL = function() {
            var host = $window.location.host;
            var landingUrl = "http://www.google.com";
            alert(landingUrl);
            $window.location.href = landingUrl;
          };
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="RedirectURLApp">
      <div ng-controller="RedirectURLCtrl">
        <h2>$window or $location to Redirect URL in AngularJS</h2>
        <p>Hello {{name}},</p>
        Click to Redirect <a href="" ng-click="RedirectToURL()">Click Me!</a>
      </div>
      <div><h4><a href="http://www.code-sample.com/2015/06/redirect-to-new-page-using-location-or.html">For more detail..</a></h4></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```